# 3D Math / 2D Rotation Calculation: Split/cut 3D model?

Tags: c#, 3d, rotation, 2d, trigonometry

I'm trying to rotate a 3D object on its Z axis (up/down).

```
public void RotateY(float angle)
{
    foreach (CoordinateVertices cv in this.GetAll<CoordinateVertices>())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cv.Coordinates.Length; i++)
        {
            Vector3 old = cv.Coordinates[i];

            float theta = Math.Atan2(old.Y, old.X) + angle;
            float rayon = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(old.X, 2) + Math.Pow(old.Y, 2));

            cv.Coordinates[i] = new Vector3(Math.Cos(theta) * rayon, Math.Sin(theta) * rayon, old.Z);
        }
    }
}
```

The trigonometry is fairly simple, and it seems to work fine, but for some reason, my 3D object gets cut in half.

[image: Comparison]

Does anybody have an idea of what's going on? I would have posted this on the maths StackExchange, but it might be a problem with my programming too, and the trigonometry is really simple.

Comment: Note: It seems to me that half the coordinates output to 0, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the bug disappeared, out of nowhere. I went on to test some more values, and they worked. I went back to the same value as before, and it worked. This is ridiculous, it always happens to me.

What's the name for that? Bugs that disappear by themselves.

Comment: @Tom Zych: Not really. Heisenbugs come back when you don't study them.

Comment: I like to say that it's a "phase of the moon" bug.

Comment: Cheshire cat bugs? Boojum bugs? D.B. Cooper bugs?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: The following is an alternative for the doing the same as the above. It took me a few minutes to realize the following solution is identical to the code initially posted.**

It should look like this:

```
double Xnew = X * cos(theta) + Y * sin(theta);
double Ynew = Y * cos(theta) - X * sin(theta);
```

Or in your code:

```
public void RotateY(float angle)
{
    foreach (CoordinateVertices cv in this.GetAll<CoordinateVertices>())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cv.Coordinates.Length; i++)
        {
            Vector3 old = cv.Coordinates[i];
            float xnew = old.X * Math.Cos(angle) + old.Y * Math.Sin(angle);
            float ynew = old.Y * Math.Cos(angle) - old.X * Math.Sin(angle);

            cv.Coordinates[i] = new Vector3(xnew, ynew, old.Z);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code assumes you're rotating about the origin. If you're not rotating about the origin, you just need to translate to the origin, rotate, then translate back.

See here for more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Rotation

Comment: Actually I was doing it right, since it works now. But thanks for trying.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that after I stared at it for a few minutes. Took me a while to realize it was exactly identical to the above code.

Comment: Yeah, it's just a translation to polar then back (around the z-axis only). Weird that it wasn't working at first, though. I suspect a bug elsewhere in the program.

Comment: Well, I've edited my posted to reflect the mistake I've made. Good luck finding your actual bug!

Comment: You didn't deserve your thumbs down. Here's an up from me. o.ô

Comment: Well I did jump the gun a bit and assume your code was wrong. I had to stare at the two before I realized the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As has been noted, nothing wrong with your code.  However, you may also be interested in using the Transform function (which can operate on your entire array of coordinates at once).  `Vector3.Transform (Vector3[], Matrix)`. You can get your rotation with a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotations_in_three_dimensions) calculated for a given angle, theta, about any axis.  I would expect this to be significantly faster for large numbers of points.  (Less trig calculations, and possibly hardware acceleration)